# NSDictionary with integer as number

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a NSDictionary with the following layout:

```
{
  1:{
    ... some data ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I have a NSNumber object with a integer value of 1, but when I do
`[my_dict objectForKey:my_number]` it returns null.

If I try and convert NSNumber to a integer via `[my dict objectForKey:[my_number intValue]]` I get a warning and the program crashes when it reaches that part of the code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keys in a `NSDictionary` or `NSMutableDictionary` must be objects, like `NSNumber`. They cannot be primitive data types, like `int`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: NSMapTable and NSHashTable *do* allow keys to be integers.  However, I don't know if they are available on the OS you are targeting.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're trying to use an integer as the key in your `NSDictionary`. This would be correct with an `NSArray`, with an `NSDictionary` actually needs a proper object as a key.

You might have more success in this particular case feeding that data into an `NSArray`, and accessing it with:

```
id *someData = [my_array objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Its actually a dictionary because im mapping ID's from a database to other information. Thanks for the help though!